# iOS 7 setContentOffset in viewDidLoad resettting to 0

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uikit

I have a `UISearchBar` attached to the top of the table view.  The idea is that when you drag down from the top you can search.

So under iOS 6 I have attached the search bar and then in the viewDidLoad I "setContentOffset" to `CGPointMake( 0, searchBar.frame.size.height )` which sets the content offset to 44.

This works perfectly for me.

However the behaviour is not the same in iOS 7.

After I do the setContentOffset in viewDidLoad,  I see an internal call to `_notifyDidScroll` which sets the content offset back to 0 (after `viewDidLoad` has completed).  The funny thing is my search bar is not at -44.

How can I make iOS6 and iOS7 behave the same way?  I don't care if iOS6 starts doing this notifyDidScroll or iOS 7 stops doing it, but i'd like consistency between both versions!

For now I have had to use a horrible solution that performs different tasks on iOS 7 and iOS6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to disable UnderTopBars in your ViewController. You can do this in the storyboard or .xib in the property of your UIViewController.

edit:

[image]

Hope that will help.

Comment: -Click on the UIViewController in the storyboard
-In the utilities (the thing in the right) click in the tab : Show the attributes inspector
-> View controller -> Extend Edges

Comment: @Nicloas:  And for non-storyboards?

Comment: Or, ideally, programmatically?

Comment: (UIRectEdge)edgesForExtendedLayout or (Bool)extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars both are UIviewController attribute

Comment: Thanks, that was the one! :)